# Change Current Cell, Without Removing the Selection

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, selection

Once I've selected multiple cells in a datagridview, I want my current cell to equal the first cell that is selected in the datagridview. The problem I'm having is, after the selection has been made (on mouse up), I set the current cell to the first selected cell (me.datagridview.currentcell =), but this removes all of the other selections in the datagridview. Does anybody know a way of changing the currentcell, without removing the datagridview selection. Current example code below:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseUp(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseUp

    a = 0
    Do While a < Me.DataGridView1.RowCount
        b = 0
        Do While b < Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b).Selected = True Then
                Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b)
                GoTo skipstep
            End If
            b += 1
        Loop
        a += 1
    Loop

    skipstep:

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the [CurrentCell](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,2147) property you'll see that  it makes a call to `ClearSelection` *before* `SetCurrentCellAddressCore`. But you cannot call "SCCAC" because it's defined as `Protected`. So my best suggestion is that you subclass the DGV and create a new public method.

```
Public Class UIDataGridView
    Inherits DataGridView

    Public Sub SetCurrentCell(cell As DataGridViewCell)
        If (cell Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("cell")
        'TODO: Add more validation:
        'ElseIf (Not cell.DataGridView Is Me) Then
        End If
        Me.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex, True, False, False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you don't want to subclass the DGV, then reflection is your only option.

```
Imports System.Reflection
```

```
Private Sub HandleCellMouseDown(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDown
    Me.firstCell = If(((e.ColumnIndex > -1) AndAlso (e.RowIndex > -1)), Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex), Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub HandleCellMouseUp(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseUp
    If ((Not Me.firstCell Is Nothing) AndAlso (Me.firstCell.Selected AndAlso (Me.DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 1))) Then

        Dim type As Type = GetType(DataGridView)
        Dim flags As BindingFlags = (BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Dim method As MethodInfo = type.GetMethod("SetCurrentCellAddressCore", flags)

        method.Invoke(Me.DataGridView1, {Me.firstCell.ColumnIndex, Me.firstCell.RowIndex, True, False, False})

        Debug.WriteLine("First cell is current: {0}", {(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell Is Me.firstCell)})

    End If
End Sub

Private firstCell As DataGridViewCell
```

PS: Did you forget that users can select cells by using the keyboard? ;)

Comment: This is a really good answer, thanks heaps. Can't get your first option to work (I'm pretty new to VB.NET, I need to play with it a little more), but your second option works like a charm. Thanks again!!!

Comment: For option 1, this is what you need to do: In the "Solution Explorer pane" right-click your application name and go to "Add > Class". Change the name to "UIDataGridView.vb" and click add. Replace the auto-generated code with the code in my answer (first part). Rebuild your solution. The custom control is now available at the top of the "Toolbox pane". You can drag and drop this control onto a form. Oh, and since you're new, here's a pro-tip: Set the strict compiler option to `On`. This is **very** important. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396